# Order Frobenius complement divides order Frobenius kernel - 1

Tags: frobenius-groups

Let $G$ be a Frobenius group with $H$ Frobenius complement and $K$ Frobenius kernel.

I read that $|H|$ divides $|K| - 1$, but I don't know why this holds, has anyone an idea?

Comment: Let $H$ act on $K$ (conjugation), $K$ will decompose as $H$-orbits, $1$ of size $1$, the others will have size $|H|$. So the result follows.
(I used the fact that $hkh^{-1} \not = k$ for $ h \not = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

I guess my answer is equivalent to the one above, but I think about this stuff from primarily a combinatorial rather than algebraic viewpoint. So: $K$ can be written as a permutation group on $|K|$ points. The Frobenius condition transfers to the statement that the Frobenius complement, written on these same points, fixes exactly one of them, and is therefore a fixed-point free permutation group on $|K| - 1$ points, thus $|H|||K| - 1$.

Comment: You are right that it is equivalent to the above comment. The action of $H$ on $K$ by conjugation is the same as the action of $H$ on the $|K|$ points you are discussing.